# Tomcat cannot look up: Cannot instantiate class: weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory

Tags: tomcat, exception, jms, weblogic, rmi

My Tomcat application is trying to publish a message to JMS topic created by Weblogic via RMI call.

I tried various ways:

- Include wlfullclient.jar to build path or copy to tomcat/server/lib and then deploy.
- The same action was performed with wlthint3client.jar.

However, I got the error:

> Cannot instantiate class: weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory

How can I fix this?